# REACT Component to REACT Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have to implement hooks in my Component, but as far as I know it is not possible using the hooks in a REACT.Component.. I am new at REACT and I don´t really have an Idea how I can convert my Component to a function correctly. Can someone show me how to convert the content from my Component to this function?

My Component:

```
import React from "react";
import { sessionId } from "../common/urlHandler";
import { Settings } from "../settings";
import { Constants } from "../common/constants.js";
import OrderHistoryService from "../services/orderHistory/orderHistoryService";
import OrderHistoryTable from "../orderHistory/orderHistoryTable";
import OrderHistoryPagination from "../orderHistory/orderHistoryPagination";
import OrderHistorySearchField from "../orderHistory/orderHistorySearchField";

export default class OrderHistoryPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const orderHistoryService = new OrderHistoryService(
      Settings.baseUrl,
      this.props.lang
    );

    this.state = {
      orderHistoryService: orderHistoryService,
      sessionId: sessionId(), 
      orderHistoryData: Constants.DummyOrderHistory,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //fixMe: fetch-Data and set orderHistoryData
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.orderHistoryData !== null) {
      return (
        <section className="section">
          <div><OrderHistorySearchField /></div>
          <div><OrderHistoryPagination /></div>
          <div><OrderHistoryTable orderHistoryData={this.state.orderHistoryData} /></div>
        </section>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

The function into I want to convert my Component:

```
export default function OrderHistoryPage () {
//fill with data from my Component 
}
```

Comment: Basically, move your code inside `componentDidMount` to `useEffect`(s), convert your state variables to `useState` and get rid of the render() function.

Comment: Yes i tried something like this but it runs in problems i couldn´t really resolve, maybe you can show me the correct implementation for this example, so there would be something i can orientate

Comment: Show what you have tried, and I will be more than happy to point out the mistakes.

Comment: Class Components and Function Components are both components

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this basically you should use `useState` for `states` and `useEffect` for `componentDidMount`. Also you should remove things that does not exist in functional components like `render` and `this`.

```
    import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
    import { sessionId } from "../common/urlHandler";
    import { Settings } from "../settings";
    import { Constants } from "../common/constants.js";
    import OrderHistoryService from "../services/orderHistory/orderHistoryService";
    import OrderHistoryTable from "../orderHistory/orderHistoryTable";
    import OrderHistoryPagination from "../orderHistory/orderHistoryPagination";
    import OrderHistorySearchField from "../orderHistory/orderHistorySearchField";
    
    export default function OrderHistoryPage (props) { 
        const orderHistoryService = new OrderHistoryService(
          Settings.baseUrl,
          props.lang
        );
    
        const [orderHistoryService, setorderHistoryService] = useState(orderHistoryService);
    
        const [sessionId, setSessionId] = useState(sessionId());
    
        const [orderHistoryData, setOrderHistoryData] = useState(Constants.DummyOrderHistory); 
    
      useEffect(()=> {
          //fixMe: fetch-Data and set orderHistoryData
       }, []);  
          return (
    
          { (orderHistoryData !== null) &&
            (<section className="section">
              <div><OrderHistorySearchField /></div>
              <div><OrderHistoryPagination /></div>
              <div><OrderHistoryTable orderHistoryData={this.state.orderHistoryData} /></div>
            </section>) }
          );
    }
```